# Finding Min duration for a set of cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

Lets say for example I have 6 durations:

```
mm:ss.00
4:03.2
4:08.2
4:03.1
4:06.4
4:01.3
4:03.3
```

And I want to find the minimum duration. How would I do that? It doesnt work if I say `=min(A1:A6)`.

I've tried using `=concatenate("00:",A1)` etc etc, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

The values I believe have been stored as text, so using `min` will not yield anything other than 0.

Prepending `00:` to each value is a start, but the values will still be text values. You can multiply each by 1 to convert them into numbers; so you'll have:

```
=concatenate("00:",A1)*1
```

Or the equivalent:

```
=("00:"&A1)*1
```

Once you have these, you can run `min` on them (and use the formatting of `m:ss.00`).

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CC0ZWxTeqYw_mspPwmJVAD42POmazKzEfr5phqEP1X4/edit?usp=sharing).